# Consult web service wsdl soap php

Tags: php, json, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to consume the web service URL https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0?wsdl and display the return in PHp or JSON, but I am not able to do because of the request XML. How to make this query?

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/cnes/v1r0/estabelecimentosaudeservice" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:filtropesquisa="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v1r0/filtropesquisaestabelecimentosaude" xmlns:filtropesquisaprecadastrocnes="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v1r0/filtropesquisaprecadastrocnes" xmlns:msfalha="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/falha/v5r0/msfalha" xmlns:dadosgerais="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cnes/v1r0/dadosgeraiscnes" xmlns:filtrolocalizacao="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v1r0/filtrolocalizacaoestabelecimentosaude" xmlns:resultadoslocalizacao="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v1r0/resultadoslocalizacaoestabelecimentosaude" xmlns:codigocnes="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cnes/v1r0/codigocnes" xmlns:precadastro="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cnes/v1r0/dadosprecadastrocnes" name="EstabelecimentoSaudeService" targetNamespace="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/cnes/v1r0/estabelecimentosaudeservice">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/cnes/v1r0/estabelecimentosaudeservice">
<xs:import id="filtropesquisa" namespace="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v1r0/filtropesquisaestabelecimentosaude" schemaLocation="https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0?WSDL&type=XSD&file=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FAdministrador%2FDownloads%2FOAG_20160318_11-20%2FRESOURCES50%2Fxsd%2Fmensageria%2Ffiltropesquisaestabelecimentosaude.v1r0.xsd"/>
<xs:import id="filtropesquisaprecadastrocnes" namespace="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v1r0/filtropesquisaprecadastrocnes" schemaLocation="https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0?WSDL&type=XSD&file=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FAdministrador%2FDownloads%2FOAG_20160318_11-20%2FRESOURCES50%2Fxsd%2Fmensageria%2Ffiltropesquisaprecadastrocnes.v1r0.xsd"/>
<xs:import id="filtrolocalizacao" namespace="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v1r0/filtrolocalizacaoestabelecimentosaude" schemaLocation="https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0?WSDL&type=XSD&file=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FAdministrador%2FDownloads%2FOAG_20160318_11-20%2FRESOURCES50%2Fxsd%2Fmensageria%2Ffiltrolocalizacaoestabelecimentosaude.v1r0.xsd"/>
<xs:import id="dadosgerais" namespace="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cnes/v1r0/dadosgeraiscnes" schemaLocation="https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0?WSDL&type=XSD&file=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FAdministrador%2FDownloads%2FOAG_20160318_11-20%2FRESOURCES50%2Fxsd%2Fcnes%2Fdadosgeraisestabelecimento%2Fdadosgeraiscnes.v1r0.xsd"/>
<xs:import id="msfalha" namespace="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/falha/v5r0/msfalha" schemaLocation="https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0?WSDL&type=XSD&file=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FAdministrador%2FDownloads%2FOAG_20160318_11-20%2FRESOURCES50%2Fxsd%2Fmensageria%2Ffalha%2Fmsfalha.v5r0.xsd"/>
<xs:import id="resultadoslocalizacao" namespace="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v1r0/resultadoslocalizacaoestabelecimentosaude" schemaLocation="https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0?WSDL&type=XSD&file=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FAdministrador%2FDownloads%2FOAG_20160318_11-20%2FRESOURCES50%2Fxsd%2Fmensageria%2Fresultadoslocalizacaoestabelecimentosaude.v1r0.xsd"/>
<xs:import id="codigocnes" namespace="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cnes/v1r0/codigocnes" schemaLocation="https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0?WSDL&type=XSD&file=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FAdministrador%2FDownloads%2FOAG_20160318_11-20%2FRESOURCES50%2Fxsd%2Fcnes%2Fcodigocnes.v1r0.xsd"/>
<xs:import id="precadastro" namespace="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cnes/v1r0/dadosprecadastrocnes" schemaLocation="https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0?WSDL&type=XSD&file=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FAdministrador%2FDownloads%2FOAG_20160318_11-20%2FRESOURCES50%2Fxsd%2Fcnes%2Fprecadastro%2Fdadosprecadastrocnes.v1r0.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="requestConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="filtropesquisa:FiltroPesquisaEstabelecimentoSaude">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
<![CDATA[ Filtro de Pesquisa. ]]>
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="responseConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="dadosgerais:DadosGeraisEstabelecimentoSaude"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="requestLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="filtrolocalizacao:FiltroLocalizacaoEstabelecimentoSaude">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
<![CDATA[ Filtro de Localização. ]]>
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="responseLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="resultadoslocalizacao:ResultadosLocalizacaoEstabelecimentoSaude">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
<![CDATA[ Resultado localização de estabelecimentos. ]]>
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="requestConsultarPrecadastroCNES">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="filtropesquisaprecadastrocnes:FiltroPesquisaPrecadastroCnes">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
<![CDATA[ Filtro Pesquisa Precadastro CNES. ]]>
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="responseConsultarPrecadastroCNES">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="precadastro:DadosPreCadastroCNES">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
<![CDATA[
Resultado com os dados de precadastro do Estabelecimento de Saúde.
]]>
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:import namespace="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/falha/v5r0/msfalha" schemaLocation="https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0?WSDL&type=XSD&file=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FAdministrador%2FDownloads%2FOAG_20160318_11-20%2FRESOURCES50%2Fxsd%2Fmensageria%2Ffalha%2Fmsfalha.v5r0.xsd"></xsd:import>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="requestConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<wsdl:part element="tns:requestConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude" name="requestConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="responseConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<wsdl:part element="tns:responseConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude" name="responseConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="requestLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<wsdl:part name="requestLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude" element="tns:requestLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="responseLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<wsdl:part name="responseLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude" element="tns:responseLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="requestConsultarPrecadastroCNES">
<wsdl:part name="requestConsultarPrecadastroCNES" element="tns:requestConsultarPrecadastroCNES"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="responseConsultarPrecadastroCNES">
<wsdl:part name="responseConsultarPrecadastroCNES" element="tns:responseConsultarPrecadastroCNES"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault">
<wsdl:part name="fault" element="msfalha:MSFalha"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="EstabelecimentoSaudeServicePortType">
<wsdl:operation name="consultarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<wsdl:documentation>
Consultar os dados básicos do Estabelecimento de Saude pelo código do CNES.
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input name="requestConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude" message="tns:requestConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude"/>
<wsdl:output name="responseConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude" message="tns:responseConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude"/>
<wsdl:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault" message="tns:EstabelecimentoSaudeFault"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="localizarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<wsdl:documentation>
Localiza os Estabelecimentos de Saude pelas coordenadas.
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input name="requestLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude" message="tns:requestLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude"/>
<wsdl:output name="responseLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude" message="tns:responseLocalizarEstabelecimentoSaude"/>
<wsdl:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault" message="tns:EstabelecimentoSaudeFault"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="consultarPrecadastroCNES">
<wsdl:documentation>
Consultar os dados básicos do precadastro do Estabelecimento de Saude pelo código do CNES.
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:input name="requestConsultarPrecadastroCNES" message="tns:requestConsultarPrecadastroCNES"/>
<wsdl:output name="responseConsultarPrecadastroCNES" message="tns:responseConsultarPrecadastroCNES"/>
<wsdl:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault" message="tns:EstabelecimentoSaudeFault"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="EstabelecimentoSaudeServiceSOAP12Binding" type="tns:EstabelecimentoSaudeServicePortType">
<soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="consultarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<wsdl:documentation>
Consultar os dados básicos do Estabelecimento de Saude pelo código do CNES.
</wsdl:documentation>
<soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault">
<soap12:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="localizarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<wsdl:documentation>
Consultar os estabelecimentos de saúde proximo a localização informada
</wsdl:documentation>
<soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault">
<soap12:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="consultarPrecadastroCNES">
<wsdl:documentation>
Consultar os dados do precadastro do Estabelecimento de Saude pelo código do CNES.
</wsdl:documentation>
<soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault">
<soap12:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="EstabelecimentoSaudeServiceSOAP11Binding" type="tns:EstabelecimentoSaudeServicePortType">
<soap11:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="consultarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<wsdl:documentation>
Consultar os dados básicos do Estabelecimento de Saude pelo código do CNES.
</wsdl:documentation>
<soap11:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap11:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap11:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault">
<soap11:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="localizarEstabelecimentoSaude">
<wsdl:documentation>
Consultar os estabelecimentos de saúde proximo a localização informada
</wsdl:documentation>
<soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault">
<soap12:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="consultarPrecadastroCNES">
<wsdl:documentation>
Consultar os dados do precadastro do Estabelecimento de Saude pelo código do CNES.
</wsdl:documentation>
<soap11:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap11:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap11:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault">
<soap11:fault name="EstabelecimentoSaudeFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="EstabelecimentoSaudeService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:EstabelecimentoSaudeServiceSOAP12Binding" name="EstabelecimentoSaudeServicePort">
<soap12:address location="https://servicos.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port binding="tns:EstabelecimentoSaudeServiceSOAP11Binding" name="EstabelecimentoSaudeServiceSOAP11Port">
<soap11:address location="https://servicos.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Request XML

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:est="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/cnes/v1r0/estabelecimentosaudeservice" xmlns:fil="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v1r0/filtropesquisaestabelecimentosaude" xmlns:cod="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cnes/v1r0/codigocnes" xmlns:cnpj="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/corporativo/pessoajuridica/v1r0/cnpj">
<soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-5FCA58BED9F27C406E14576381084652">
            <wsse:Username>CNES.PUBLICO</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">cnes#2015public</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>

   <soap:Body>
      <est:requestConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude>
         <fil:FiltroPesquisaEstabelecimentoSaude>
            <cod:CodigoCNES>
               <cod:codigo>2530031</cod:codigo>
            </cod:CodigoCNES>
         </fil:FiltroPesquisaEstabelecimentoSaude>
      </est:requestConsultarEstabelecimentoSaude>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$proxyhost = isset($_POST['proxyhost']) ? $_POST['proxyhost'] : '';
$proxyport = isset($_POST['proxyport']) ? $_POST['proxyport'] : '';
$proxyusername = isset($_POST['proxyusername']) ? $_POST['proxyusername'] : '';
$proxypassword = isset($_POST['proxypassword']) ? $_POST['proxypassword'] : '';
$useCURL = isset($_POST['usecurl']) ? $_POST['usecurl'] : '0';
$client = new nusoap_client('https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cnes/EstabelecimentoSaudeService/v1r0', false,
                        $proxyhost, $proxyport, $proxyusername, $proxypassword);
$client->setUseCurl($useCURL);

$params = array(    'cod:codigo'=>"2530031");
$result = $client->call('consultarEstabelecimentoSaude', $params);
if ($client->fault) {
    echo '<h2>Fault (Expect - The request contains an invalid SOAP body)</h2><pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
} else {
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    } else {
        echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
    }
}
?>
```

You need to download [nusoap](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)

Also [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) will definitely help you on your tests

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WSDL to php generator as you won't wonder how to construct the request and you'll easily handle the response.

Try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) poject, it's easy. Or online at https://providr.io